# How to get a *lazy* list to play nice with other environments

Tags: paragraphs, grouping

I've created a *lazy itemize* command.  Partially I've just done it for the hell of it:  to see if I could create a command to do what I want it to.  Partially to try to get to understand better how `\par` and `\everypar` behave.

The underlying idea behind the *lazy itemize* command is that each item is its own paragraph:  in other words, a *lazy list* isn't really a list at all, but a specially formatted paragraph.

Here's my code that seems to work in isolation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% definig the *lazy list*:  which really isn't a list at all!
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter

%% a macro to set parameters for the *lazy list*
\newcommand\aelistset[1]{\pgfkeys{/ae/list/setter/.cd,#1}}

%% key interface for setting *lazy list* parameters
\pgfkeys{/ae/list/setter/.cd,
  item mark/.code=\def\ae@item@mark{#1},
  item sep/.code=\setlength\ae@lazylist@sep{#1},
  left margin/.code={\setlength\ae@lazylist@lm{#1}},
  right margin/.code={\setlength\ae@lazylist@rm{#1}},
  margins/.code={\setlength\ae@lazylist@lm{#1}%%
                \setlength\ae@lazylist@rm{#1}},%%
  }

%% *lazy list* parameters
\newlength\ae@lazylist@sep
\newlength\ae@lazylist@lm
\newlength\ae@lazylist@rm
\newcommand\ae@item@mark{}

%% setting default *lazy list* parameters
\aelistset{%%
  item mark=$\bullet$,
  item sep=1ex,
  margins=2em}

%% conditional to determine whether current *lazy item*
%% is preceded by another *lazy item*
\newif\if@is@ae@lazyitem

%% *lazy item* command
\newcommand\lazyitem{%%
  \if@is@ae@lazyitem
  \else
    \global\let\ae@old@par\par
  \fi
  \bgroup
    \gdef\par{\if@is@ae@lazyitem\fi
              \vspace{\ae@lazylist@sep}\ae@old@par\noindent
              \gdef\par{\vspace{\ae@lazylist@sep}\ae@old@par
                        \@is@ae@lazyitemfalse
                        \global\let\par\ae@old@par}}%%
    \par
    \makebox[\ae@lazylist@lm]{\ae@item@mark}%%
    \gdef\ae@parshape{%%
      \parshape 2 0pt             \dimexpr\columnwidth-\ae@lazylist@rm\relax
                  \ae@lazylist@lm \dimexpr\columnwidth-\ae@lazylist@lm-\ae@lazylist@rm\relax}%%
  \global\@is@ae@lazyitemtrue
  \aftergroup\ae@parshape
  \egroup
  }

\makeatother

\aelistset{%%
  item mark=$\star$,
  item sep=2ex,
  margins=2em,
  right margin=0pt}  

\begin{document}

Hello world this is my test case for an \verb=\lazyitem=
\lipsum[3]
\lazyitem His rebus adducti et auctoritate Orgetorigis permoti
      constituerunt ea quae ad proficiscendum pertinerent comparare,
      iumentorum et carrorum quam maximum numerum coemere, sementes
      quam maximas facere, ut in itinere copia frumenti suppeteret,
      cum proximis civitatibus pacem et amicitiam confirmare.
\lazyitem Ad eas res conficiendas biennium sibi satis esse duxerunt; in
      tertium annum profectionem lege confirmant. Ad eas res
      conficiendas Orgetorix deligitur. Is sibi legationem ad
      civitates suscipit. In eo itinere persuadet Castico,
      Catamantaloedis filio, Sequano, cuius pater regnum in Sequanis
      multos annos obtinuerat et a senatu populi Romani amicus
      appellatus erat, ut regnum in civitate sua occuparet, quod pater
      ante habuerit; itemque Dumnorigi Haeduo, fratri Diviciaci, qui
      eo tempore principatum in civitate obtinebat ac maxime plebi
      acceptus erat, ut idem conaretur persuadet eique filiam suam in
      matrimonium dat.
\lazyitem Perfacile factu esse illis probat conata perficere, propterea
      quod ipse suae civitatis imperium obtenturus esset: non esse
      dubium quin totius Galliae plurimum Helvetii possent; se suis
      copiis suoque exercitu illis regna conciliaturum confirmat. Hac
      oratione adducti inter se fidem et ius iurandum dant et regno
      occupato per tres potentissimos ac firmissimos populos totius
      Galliae sese potiri posse sperant.  
\lipsum[1-2]
\lazyitem Hello there.

\end{document}
```

I *know* that the `\bgroup` and `\egroup` here isn't really doing much since everything on the inside of the group is globalized, but my intentions were to *potentially* do destructive stuff within this group that I don't want to effect the rest of the document.  So, though not necessary for this MWE, I've left them in.

But this doesn't play well if embedded in a regular list environment:

```
Hello world this is my test case for an \verb=\lazyitem=
\lipsum[3]
\begin{itemize}
\item this is the first

\lazyitem His rebus adducti et auctoritate Orgetorigis permoti
      constituerunt ea quae ad proficiscendum pertinerent comparare,
      iumentorum et carrorum quam maximum numerum coemere, sementes
      quam maximas facere, ut in itinere copia frumenti suppeteret,
      cum proximis civitatibus pacem et amicitiam confirmare.
\lazyitem Ad eas res conficiendas biennium sibi satis esse duxerunt; in
      tertium annum profectionem lege confirmant. Ad eas res
      conficiendas Orgetorix deligitur. Is sibi legationem ad
      civitates suscipit. In eo itinere persuadet Castico,
      Catamantaloedis filio, Sequano, cuius pater regnum in Sequanis
      multos annos obtinuerat et a senatu populi Romani amicus
      appellatus erat, ut regnum in civitate sua occuparet, quod pater
      ante habuerit; itemque Dumnorigi Haeduo, fratri Diviciaci, qui
      eo tempore principatum in civitate obtinebat ac maxime plebi
      acceptus erat, ut idem conaretur persuadet eique filiam suam in
      matrimonium dat.
\lazyitem Perfacile factu esse illis probat conata perficere, propterea
      quod ipse suae civitatis imperium obtenturus esset: non esse
      dubium quin totius Galliae plurimum Helvetii possent; se suis
      copiis suoque exercitu illis regna conciliaturum confirmat. Hac
      oratione adducti inter se fidem et ius iurandum dant et regno
      occupato per tres potentissimos ac firmissimos populos totius
      Galliae sese potiri posse sperant.  
\item this is the second
\item this is the third
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lazyitem Hello there.
```

Several things are going wonky here, but the only one that I'm concerned about is how the *normal* (non-lazy) LaTeX `itemize` *forgets* where the left margin is.

I tried to get around this by embedding my `lazy items` within their own groups.  Here's how I attempted to do that:

```
%% *lazy item* command
\newcommand\lazyitem{%%
  \if@is@ae@lazyitem
  \else
    \global\let\ae@old@par\par
  \fi
  %\bgroup
    \gdef\par{\if@is@ae@lazyitem\egroup\fi
              \vspace{\ae@lazylist@sep}\ae@old@par\noindent\bgroup%%
              \gdef\par{\vspace{\ae@lazylist@sep}\egroup\ae@old@par%%
                        \@is@ae@lazyitemfalse
                        \global\let\par\ae@old@par}}%%
    \par
    \makebox[\ae@lazylist@lm]{\ae@item@mark}%%
    \gdef\ae@parshape{%%
      \parshape 2 0pt             \dimexpr\columnwidth-\ae@lazylist@rm\relax
                  \ae@lazylist@lm \dimexpr\columnwidth-\ae@lazylist@lm-\ae@lazylist@rm\relax}%%
  \global\@is@ae@lazyitemtrue
  %\aftergroup
  \ae@parshape
  %\egroup
  }
```

But working with this definition I get an error about too many brackets.

Could someone point out how this is happening?

Comment: Using `\parshape` inside a `list` environment (like `itemize`) is a sure recipe for disaster.

Comment: @egreg That's why I was trying to wrap things in  group.  So, why is my grouping not working out.  As I count it the `\bgroup` and `\egroup` tokens should all be matched.

Comment: Inside a `list` environment, also `\par` is redefined and you redefine it as well, so the least that can happen is that TeX is confused. If you do `\bgroup\gdef\par{...}\egroup` the group serves no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: grouping doesn't help at all, the shape of the list item is set by setting parshape (and local definitions of \par) so if you redefine parshape you lose all the outer list shape and indentation, whether you set it inside a group or not